# 'perfectly cromulent word' Is "cromulent" a predicate adjective?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

Given its first use:

> "I don't know why, it's a perfectly cromulent word."

The verb is "is" (=> it's) and the noun is "word". Since *cromulent* links them both **and** directly addresses the noun, isn't that the definition of a Predicate Adjective?

Has it been used in any other way?

Comment: Google reports 91K instances of *is a cromulent* [word, whatever] but only 55 instances of *is cromulent to* [do something]. For comparison, *is a stupid* [thing to do, whatever] gets 300M hits, and *is stupid to* [do it] gets 16M. Does that answer your question by showing that *cromulent* isn't often used as flexibly as a functionally similar word like *stupid*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can see what you mean, although I'm not sure a [GoogleFight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=cromulent&word2=Embiggens) is a fair measure of er, correct use. Thanks for the stats, though :)

Comment: Well, with a neologism like this, "correct" usage is obviously *defined* by "actual" usage, so I think it's as good a mechanism as any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not being used in the predicative role / position:

1. **Bill is *skillful*.** Link verb + predicative adjective.
2. **Bill is *a plumber*.** Link verb + predicative noun group.
3. **Bill is *a skillful plumber*.** Link verb + predicative noun group, where noun group contains an attributive adjective.

3'. **Bill is *a really skillful plumber*.** Degree modifier (intensifier) added to predicative noun group.

Answer (score 3):

In English, in **any** clause of the shape
 - [`Noun Phrase` [`be` `Adjective`]]
the `Adjective` is a Predicate Adjective.

It's an Adjective **and** it's the [Predicate](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).
That's the **definition** of *Predicate Adjective*.

In **exactly** the same way, in any clause of the shape
  - [`Noun Phrase` [`be` `Noun Phrase`]]
the **second** `Noun Phrase` is a *Predicate Noun*.

It's a Noun **and** it's the Predicate.
That's the definition of *Predicate Noun*.

This works for any noun or any adjective, whether it's artificial or natural.
This is grammar, not dictionary.

Comment: And, by the way, Predicate Adjectives do not "modify" anything. They're predicates; everything else "modifies" them.

Comment: I suppose your "be" is just the lexical equivalent of **=** or **≈** (that second one meaning *is approximately equal to*), so it applies equally to verbs like *seems, appears, looks,* etc.

Comment: Oh, no. The verb _be_ in this context has no reference, meaning, or lexical equivalent at all. It's entirely a dummy verb, doing nothing more than opening a place (usually contracted, of course) for the tense to appear. No semantics at all. Totally syntactic, automatic, and meaningless, like _Do_-Support.

Comment: Umm... does that space have to at least be filled by a *verb?*

Comment: It has to be filled by something that can be inflected for tense, which means a verb; but which one is specified by rule: _be_ + _-ing_ for Progressive, _be_ + _-en_ for Passive, _have_ + _-en_ for Perfect, _be_ + Adj, _be_ + NP, _be_ + PP, etc.